как объединить tkinter и telebot?
Написал программу на tkinter и бота на telebot при помощи которой можно управлять программой (код программы и бота находятся в разных файлах и в боте я просто вызываю функции из файла с gui). Только вот если я запускаю бота, то он не запускает программу, а если программу то бота. Пытался разделить потоки при помощи threading, но не получаете. Если запустить просто два файла по отдельности, то будет ошибка RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop. И как сделать, чтобы бот и gui на tkinter работали вместе?

Эта ошибка говорит о том, что mainloop из tkinter должен работать в основном потоке. Вот пробуйте tkinter приложение писать как обычно, а бота выносить в отдельный поток.

Вам нужно запустить два приложения в разных процессах.
Например:
python app.py
python bot.py

Бот и приложение будут запущены в разных процессах, и будут работать одновременно.
Учтите, что процессы не делят между собой оперативную память, то есть синхронизировать данные вам нужно через отдельное хранилище, например, postgres и тому подобное.
